# Crear notificación sin sonido y vibración (Android)

Tags: android

¿Hay opción al crear una notificación en Android para que, no suene y no vibre?

Gracias

Comment: Si, agrega tu código y a partir de el podemos ayudarte modificando y explicando, recuerda [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, es posible, con este método puedes crear una `notificación` y como y donde controlar el `sonido` y la `vibración` de la misma.

```
public void Notification(){

    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Standard);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Informacion");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});  //<--- Aqui defines intervalos de vibracion
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);     //<--- Aqui controlas la vibracion
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

         notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .addAction(R.drawable.simplebutton, "Nombre de boton en notificacion", actionPendingIntent)//actionPendingIntent, es el intent que se ejecutara cuando se clickee el boton de la notificacion.
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.drawable_icon_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Titulo")
            .setColor(color)
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.beeep)) //<--Aqui estableces el sonido
            .setContentText("Texto que desees")
            .setContentInfo("Texto de informacion");

    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build())
```

> señale los puntos claves con comentarios, sin esas lineas podrás hacer
>   lo que planteaste en tu pregunta.

Comment: Ante este tipo de preguntas no se debe responder, hay que decirle al autor que la edite para que cumpla las normas del sitio. Lo único que se consigue respondiendo a estas preguntas es que los OP no se esfuercen nada ni muestren interés.

Comment: Ayudanos con lo que comenta @PabloSimonDiEstefano  por cierto con esto va a suceder lo que no quiere el usuario:  notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});  //<--- Aqui defines intervalos de vibracion
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);

Comment: @Jorgesys , si lo tendré en cuenta, soy nuevo dando respuestas, y con respecto a lo del código, si lo se, por eso lo señale en el comentario, para que vea y haga pruebas de como funciona con y sin esa linea. Debo editarlo

Comment: @DavidVillegas al contrario gracias a tí que veo participas en el sitio y das muy buenas respuestas. Te comentaré que por experiencia en ocasiones el OP luego no pregunta lo que entendemos =-| te lo comento porque me ha sucedido, lo mejor es que agregué un poco de su código. En una ocasión "notificación" de la que hablaba el OP en realidad era un "Widget" =.) hehe