# Poner sonido a mi notificación Android

Tags: android, servicio, notificaciones, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Quiero poner un sonido concreto (.mp3) a mi notificación en android por un servicio que corre en segundo plano, pero siempre suena el sonido por defecto, muestro mi código:

```
private Notification getNotification() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);

    text = Utils.dameCoordenadas(mLocation);

    // Extra para ayudarnos a averiguar si llegamos a onStartCommand a través de la notificación o no.
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

    // El PendingIntent que lleva a una llamada a onStartCommand () en este servicio.
    PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // El PendingIntent para lanzar la actividad.
    PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launch, getString(R.string.launch_activity),
                    activityPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates),
                    servicePendingIntent)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentTitle(Utils.dameTituloNotificacionLocalizacion(this))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(text)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
    }

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    return builder.build();
}
```

He probado a añadir el método .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_sound) y he probado a darme solución con esta repuesta: [Crear notificación sin sonido y vibración (Android)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/186839/crear-notificaci%c3%b3n-sin-sonido-y-vibraci%c3%b3n-android), pero siempre suena el sonido por defecto. Lo estoy probando en un tlf real (Samsung A40) con android Q. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Muy importante tener definido en el AndroidManifest.xml el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

y realizar su [petición manual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24932/error-al-mostrar-el-directorio-externo-de-archivos-en-android-6-0-read-external)

Esta es a forma de realizar la carga del sonido personalizado definido en `/raw`

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_sound);

 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, soundUri );
```

Comment: He añadido el permiso al manifest y solicitado en el main. Ahora me da error porque falta solicitar permisos de WRITE_SETTINGS. Los añado, pero me da error. Añado lo siguiente en el onCreate:   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {   if(!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {  Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));  startActivityForResult(intent, 200); pero continúa el sonido por defecto. En el método que se ejecuta en el servicio getNotification() es donde he inicializado Uri y RingtoneManager

Comment: No sé si soy yo, el caso es que después de añadir los permisos necesarios tanto WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE como WRITE_SETTINGS, aunque la app se ejecuta bien, sigue sonado el sonido por defecto.

Comment: Aunque me acabo de dar cuenta, porque he recibido una videollamada por Whatsapps, que lo que se ha cambiado es el tono por defecto de la videollamada. Puedo dar fe de ello, porque ese mp3 no lo tenía en el móvil.